# Remove object from Django query list in for

Tags: python, django

I would like to exclude some objects from a query list based on a number of checks - the first a simple for loop that checks if each item has 'expired'. However, when ever I do this, it returns all objects.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
food = Food.objects.filter(user=self.user, in_cupboard=True)

          for f in food:
              if (f.cupboard.close_date + timedelta(days=1)) < now:
                  f.exclude(pk=f.id)
```

What is the correct way to 'filter' objects using a for list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the problem is that you exclude the item from `f` where you should exclude it from `food`, also you need to store that new queryset, like:

```
valid_food = food
for f in food:
    if (f.cupboard.close_date + timedelta(days=1)) < now:
        valid_food = valid_food.exclude(pk=f.id)
```

But the filtering could be done only with django ORM, like this:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
food = Food.objects.filter(
    user=self.user,
    in_cupboard=True,
    close_date__gt=today,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

why are you not using exclude of django query

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
food = Food.objects.filter(user=self.user, in_cupboard=True).exclude(expires_at__lt = now)
```

Comment: Unfortunately don't believe I can do this given that its a property

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to just make a list and not use the `filter` or `exclude` function in django, you could simply use list filters in python.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
food = Food.objects.filter(user=self.user, in_cupboard=True)
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: (x.cupboard.close_date + timedelta(days=1)) < now, food))
```